# multiple of same form on a page

Tags: django, django-forms

So what I'm trying to figure out here is how to create a form for each of these items such that it can be submitted to add a note for that one student.  If that one note wasn't filled out then it will receive an error notice just for that one form note.  This is just a quick example I put together to try to get input on this.  I'm not sure what kind of formset I need here that will allow me to display the all the Exam object info while having a form there too.

edit: so possibly I think I have a solution.
I'm doing a

```
examscores = Exam.objects.all()
NoteFormset = formset_factory(NoteForm, extra = len(examscores))
notesets = NoteFormset()
examscores_and_forms = zip(examscores, notesets.forms)
```

Then in the template I'm doing {% for exam, form in examscores_and_forms %}
this seems to be yielding some results.  I just need to hide the id of the object and and get_object_or_404 if the form is valid and changed.  I'll further update this later with a full solution.

**views.py**

```
def studentscores(request):
    examscores = Exam.objects.all()

    if request.POST:
        form = NoteForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            pass
            return HttpResponseRedirect( request.get_full_path() )
        else:
            return render_to_response('exams.html', { 'examscores': examscores, 'form': form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = NoteForm()
        return render_to_response('exams.html', { 'examscores': examscores, 'form': form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname  = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.firstname and self.lastname:
            fullname = self.firstname + " " + self.lastname
            return fullname
        else:
            return self.firstname


class Note(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    note    = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.student)


class Exam(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    score   = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.student) + " " + str(self.score)
```

**forms.py**

```
class NoteForm(forms.Form):
    note = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

**template**

```
{% for exam in examscores %}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ exam.student }}</td>
        <td>{{ exam.score }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form.as_p }}</td>
        <td><button type="submit" name="action" value="addnote" />Note</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `inlineformset_factory` you can handle many of them in your view. Below I've described some important steps that you can use to dynamically create the forms (handling of them is a handling of one formset object in your view and it simple like one form):

1) render it's formset to your template, look at rendered html structure, create empty form template `<script type="text/html" id="formset-item-template">__item-widget__</script>` and maybe split it to skeleton and widgets `<script type="text/html" id="image-item-widget"></script>`.

2) Load that template in your scripts block of other (main for this view) template. Provide some js function to handle adding form.

3) Get your skeletons `var tempItemWidgetMarkup = $('#select-item-widget').html();` and compile them setting new `id`and `name` and smth else you need using `replace`:

`itemWidgetMarkup = tempItemWidgetMarkup.replace(/__options-set__/g, tempStr);`.

4) Increment total forms value `$(this).siblings('fieldset').find('div input[name$="TOTAL_FORMS"]').val(itemsCount + 1);` also check `MAX_NUM_FORMS` value and increment if you have more then 1000 forms.

5) When "compiling" is done - add it to your fieldset `$(compiledTemplateMarkup).hide().appendTo($(this).siblings('fieldset')).fadeIn(1000);`

Try and if I've missed smth (everytime do that) - ask :)

**Update**:

That is how you should set initial data to formset:

```
examscores = Exam.objects.values()  # returns dictionary
NoteFormset = formset_factory(NoteForm, extra=0)  # or change extra to how many empty forms you want
formset = NoteFormset(initial=examscores)
```

Comment: I just came back to see if there was any comments on this.  I actually just now was looking into inlineformset_factory.  Trying to figure out how I can tie in displaying the object that shares a FK with the form I'm submitting.  I might have to edit my above question to illustrate this.  Thank you for getting back.

Comment: `how I can tie in displaying the object that shares a FK with the form I'm submitting` if you creating that object and there are another fields besides FK then `form` from example should be instance of your `object` class ModelForm

Comment: `form_2` is your formset, so `form_2.instance = self.object` tie formset with object

Comment: I've included a full example now of what I'm trying to achieve.  If you could take a look and possibly comment.  Thank you.

Comment: Better use official way set initial data to formset https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset . I will update my answer ...

Comment: and don't use `len`, for queryset there is `count()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count `Exam.objects.count()`

Comment: also recommend use `generic views` it is more readable and clear way https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview and createview

Comment: Thank for the count() tip.  Why formset = NoteFormset(initial=examscores) ?  Going to look into generic views here in a bit.  Thanks for getting back.

Comment: Because you want set initial data to your formset, and it is right semantical documented way for doing that, `extra` used to specify additional `empty` form, but you hardcode objects to it (dirty and slower way)